# as3 change properties on mc using instance string name

Tags: actionscript-3, target

I have many buttons in a movie clip. Rather than creating listeners for each I just want to perform an action based on what target they clicked in the mc. I want to do change the alpha based on the button they click on. How can this be done?

I tried 4 options below and none of these work.

```
      manyButtons.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

function mDown(e:Event)
        {
trace(e.target.name); // Works! Outputs name of button I click              
this[e.target.name].alpha = .5; // Does not work
e.target.name.alpha = .5; // Error: can not create property alpha on sting
e.target.alpha = .5; // changes ALL children buttons and parent mc.
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The e.target.name returns you the name of your button, as you've observed that already. But your button is not in "this". It is in this.manyButtons. You have to provide the full path. So the solution is:

```
this.manyButtons[e.target.name].alpha = .5;
```

...assuming that the buttons are children of the manyButtons display object.

Btw, a better approach would be simply this:

```
MovieClip(e.target).alpha = .5
```

EDIT: if you are coming from AS2 -> remember the scope does not change in listener anymore. In case you wrote something like this before, forget it:

```
this.manyButtons.onRelease = function() {
   trace(this); //this changed the scope to the manyButtons object!
}
```

`this` does not change anymore in as3. It always refers to the object it is declared in!

Comment: Awesome. I knew it was possible. I used MovieClip(e.target).alpha = .5. HOW on earth is a person supposed to know this without stackoverflow? My goodness. Thanks so much!

Comment: @PapaDeBeau Well, everyday something new, isn't it? Glad to help! Just remember from every event you can actually retrieve the object that triggered it (e.target) and the object that your listener was assigned to (e.currentTarget). So in your case the currentTarget was manyButtons, while target was the particular button. currentTarget and target differ ONLY for display objects. Once you have the references... well, just do whatever you want to do with them! You don't need any paths, etc. anymore. :)

Comment: Ok, one last question. It looks funny with the whole button and text going alpha so I named the button "myButton" so I figured this would work: MovieClip(e.target).myButton.alpha = .5; But... it doesn't. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau (not quite sure what you mean but...) Your "myButton" is a button inside of "manyButtons", isn't it? In that case it won't work because the e.target IS the myButton. So e.target.myButton looks for an instance of myButton inside your myButton which, of course, doesn't exist. But maybe I just understood it wrong.

Comment: No, sorry, bad naming. For example I have a button called "One" this is inside manyButtons, so is Two, Three, etc.. but inside each of One,Two, etc.. there is now a MovieClip called "myButton". So the path for the first button would be. manyButtons.One.myButton.alpha. So myButton is in all the button children inside manyButtons. Again, bad naming, but I hope you understand now.

Comment: Well, why don't you just trace(e.target.name) and you will see the result /and I think you will understand it better as well/. Remember: e.target contains the target object = what you clicked. So in this case if you click the "myButton", e.target will be simply myButton. Create a big Movieclip. Position several small Movieclips into it. Give them all instance names and assign a click listener and trace(e.target.name). You will see that if you click the small clips, you will get their names. If you click on the big one (their container), where they don't cover it, you will get it's name.

Comment: With other words: (e.target).myButton does not exist if you click the myButton. Because in that case e.target is the myButton.

Comment: ahhh I got it. Yes, I figured it out. Its the same answer as you posted above. Its working now. Not sure why it didn't before. You rock my friend. Thanks so much for your help. :)